# Difference between getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

From my understanding,

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

should return the same things. However, when I try to remove the class from all the elements using

```
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i)
  elems[i].className = "";
```

I get different results. `querySelectorAll` successfully removes the classes from all the elements, but `getElementsByClassName` only removes the classes from about half the elements.

What's going on?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return live DOM elements. Subsequent changes to the structure of the underlying document won't be reflected in the NodeList object returned by `querySelectorAll`. This means that the object will instead contain a list of matching Element nodes that were in the document at the time the list was created.

`getElementsByClassName` returns live DOM elements. Any subsequent change made to those DOM elements would be reflected in the list.

Comment: What does "live DOM element" mean?

Comment: An [*HTMLCollection*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0).

Comment: That's it!  
And comes very handy, dealing with AJAX calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Anirudha's answer, when you change the class names on the live list of elements retrieved by `getElementsByClassName`, you're reducing the number of results (since the elements available in the list are only there because they have the class name).

Thus your `elems.length` property is being reduced by one with every iteration, and you only make it through half the elements.