# Why does querySelectorAll sometimes return live DOM elements?

Tags: javascript

querySelectorAll [doesn't return live DOM elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473180/7238242)  However unless I'm missing something this isn't true for all properties.

**Question:**  I tested  `querySelectorAll` with the `.innerHTML` property. Instead of returning the number 5 that was present when the document was created it returned the word FIVE that was inserted with Javascript.  Why is this?

As a control I tested `querySelectorAll` with the `.length` property and it returned the number 10 as anticipated.

I must be missing a key concept about `querySelectorAll` but I'm not sure what that is.  My code is below.  Thanks so much!

```js
var largeContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".box_1");
  
document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[9].className = "box_2";    
console.log(largeContainer.length);
  
document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[5].innerHTML = "FIVE";  
console.log(largeContainer[5].innerHTML);
```

```css
.box_1 {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.box_2 {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1">0</div>
<div class="box_1">1</div>
<div class="box_1">2</div>
<div class="box_1">3</div>
<div class="box_1">4</div>
<div class="box_1">5</div>
<div class="box_1">6</div>
<div class="box_1">7</div>
<div class="box_1">8</div>
<div class="box_1">9</div>
```

Comment: the difference is the difference between elements and their content

Comment: That's because your variable `largeContainer` contains a collection of element which you collect before applying changes to the class. If you change the `class` name before you run the `.querySelectorAll()` I'm sure your results will be as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), you are correct that it returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) i.e. the set of elements it did select during installation doesn't change.

However, these [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) in the NodeList are references to the existing DOM elements (live nodes). Hence any change to those elements will be reflected in subsequent access.

Comment: I took the liberty to make some big changes in your wording, feel free to roll-back the edit if you feel I mis-interpreted your sayings.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.  I read about `NodeLists` here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList.  If I understand the reference correctly `.length` is the only property of a `NodeList`.  If that's correct does it mean that `.length` is the only thing that remains static?

Comment: Umm.. Yes, If you put it that way.. The reality, No new Element reference is added to or deleted from that list. Moreover the Element references in the List that remains const. 
To understand better, Say you have an element `e` which was already in the Nodelist you selected. Now, you remove/destroy the element, Next, createElement with exactly the same properties. Now when you try to access element `e` from that list you will get errors as the reference is now points to nothing/null.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `var largeContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".box_1");` selects all DOM elements with the class `box_1`.  If you change the class later, `largeContainer` is still referring to those DOM elements, not the selector that was once used to get them.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of returning the number 5 that was present when the document
>   was created it returned the word FIVE that was inserted with
>   Javascript. Why is this?

The code at Question gets `.innerHTML` of the element at

```
console.log(largeContainer[5].innerHTML);
```

after the `.innerHTML` is set at the element at

```
document.getElementsByClassName("box_1")[5].innerHTML = "FIVE";
```