# Javascript for deleting DIV that blurs website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, webbrowser-control

There is a website with the following div:

```
<div class="x" style="user-select: none; filter: blur(4px);">
```

under this div there are a lot of other divs. I would like to know if there is any possibility to delete only this DIV with javascript. So only that one gets deleted and all the divs underneath remain.

I want to get rid of this DIV becouse this div blurs an part of the website text. Just changing the  blur(4px) wont work the website has some kind of protection what refreshes this part back to original.
the reason i am searching for an possibility in javascript is because i want to automate this in the browser.(Just deleting DIV manually under developer mode works)

so far i got the following:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('page-content');
div.remove();  //(but this does not work)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection. Only single objects have `remove()` method. You have to apply one of the following:

1. Use brackets to specify an index of the object you want to get:

`div[0].remove()`

2. Use `item()` method passing the index as well:

`div.item(0).remove()`

Both ways are equivalent.

As an alternative, you may call `querySelector()` method:

`const div = document.querySelector('.page-content')`

It returns a single object (according to the passed CSS selector) so you can use:

`div.remove()`

**Edit:**

To remove only the covering `div`, you may use `replaceWith()` method and pass the child nodes of that div as an argument:

`div.replaceWith(...div.childNodes)`

If you want to keep only element nodes, use `children` property:

`div.replaceWith(...div.children)`

Comment: but this wil delet also everything that is inside this div. i only need to delet the div but not the content of the div

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but can you may tel me how to get it working? Because i'm new to javascript. i tried something like this but didn't work:

const div = document.querySelector('.page-content');
div.replaceWith(div.childNodes);

Comment: You missed "..." before div.childNodes.

Comment: great! now there is only one problem left there are multple (class="page-content") the script does it only to the first one. How do i make it do this to all of the div's met this class?

Comment: Just replace querySelector() with querySelectorAll().

Comment: So i tryed the following: const div = document.querySelectorAll('.page-content');
div.replaceWith(...div.children); but this seems to do nothing.

Comment: querySelectorAll() returns a collection. It doesn't have replaceWith() method. If you would like to perform an action on all elements, use forEach() like this: div.forEach((elem) => { elem.replaceWith(...elem.children); })

Comment: Glad I could help you! By the way, you may read the difference between getElementsByClassName() and querySelectorAll(): [getElementsByClassName() vs querySelectorAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473141/difference-between-getelementsbyclassname-and-queryselectorall). I recommend you to read both first and the second answer. May be useful for you. Cheers!